# How to delete an item in a listbox with a regex

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, matrix, listbox

I am trying to delete an item which is in a listbox "in a smart way". I found an alternative to my problem but I don't like it.

My program is a matrix calculator. All my matrices are in a dictionary and I "print" them in a listbox in the graphical interface.

My alternative is to delete all items in the listbox, remove the selected matrix in my dictionary and re-add all the matrices in the listbox.

So my problem is that I need to find the index of the item I want to delete, and delete it, but the var `index` is always equals to `-1`. I look for a solution and I found that i needed to override the methodes `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()` and maybe `ToString()`. I wonder if there is any better solution.

```
 public static String Delete ()
     {
         String matrix = matches[0].Groups[2].ToString();
         if (Calculatrice.listMatrix.ContainsKey(matrix))
         {
             Matrix m = Calculatrice.listMatrix[matrix];

             int index = Calculatrice.mainWindow.ListBox_display.Items.IndexOf(m);

             Calculatrice.mainWindow.ListBox_display.Items.RemoveAt(index);

             Calculatrice.listMatrix.Remove(matrix);

             return "Done!\n";
         }
         throw new Exception("The matrix does not exist.\n");
     }
```

If you want to know my Regex, this is it: `private static Regex delete_rgx  = new Regex(@"^(delete)\((\w+)\)$");`

I'm new to the StackOverflow community, and I will listen to all your suggestion for my problem and also for how to make a better question, explanation, etc.

Comment: Make sure the **objects** in listMatrix are the same as in ListBox_display.Items e.g. have the same reference/memory adress. (Not a copy or a clone) then the above code will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects in `ListBox_display` are probably not the exact objects as in your `listMatrix` dictionary.

The **[IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589122%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** function will return the index  of the specific object (just like you want) but in your case if the object in the dictionary is not the same object in the listbox you will get a -1.

Try populating the Listbox using `listMatrix.Values`